# Android garbage collection after Thread finishes

Tags: android, multithreading, garbage-collection, concurrenthashmap

I have some background threads in my app.
I have a class where I run the background threads. 
The currently running threads are stored in a Map

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Thread> actThreads = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Thread>();
```

When a thread has finished is always call:

```
actThreads.remove(key);
```

My question is: is the remove enough for the garbage to free all the memory for my thread?

Answer (score 0):

if you `import android.os.Thread` you are using android thread otherwise you are using default `java.lang.Thread` in both cases:

> Many uses of stop should be replaced by code that simply modifies some
>   variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running. The
>   target thread should check this variable regularly, and **return from**
>   **its run method** in an orderly fashion if the variable indicates that it
>   is to stop running. If the target thread waits for long periods (on a
>   condition variable, for example), the interrupt method should be used
>   to interrupt the wait

Comment: Both methods are deprecated